# How to find definition of predefined code in Oracle 9i?

Tags: sql, database, oracle9i

I am using Oracle 9i and want to know to the definition(code) of predefined
functions in Oracle like,REVERSE(),REPLACE().
Is there any library of oracle where i can serach these library functions!

Please Suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Oracle wraps the body (implementation) of virtually all of its packages, and the functions you've mentioned are part of the STANDARD package.